# Hide tk window and display only message box

Tags: python, tkinter

How to display only message box and hide the tk modal window? It would be great if someone can modify this below.

```
import time
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw

def timer(hours):
    seconds = hours * 60
    start = time.time()

    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:

        time.sleep(0.0010)
        elapsed = time.time() - start

    elapsed = elapsed//60

    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Done", "Done Today" +str(elapsed) + " Hrs")

timer(1)
```

Comment: As a note, avoid using `time.sleep()` in a gui program- it will prevent the gui from updating, meaning it can't display each tick as the Tcl loop won't get control. Instead, have your function call itself `after` a set period of time via a `root.after([milliseconds],[function])` call. This will allow Tcl/Tk to update the gui and also won't freeze up everything (i.e. with `sleep` your buttons won't do anything until the mainloop gets control)

Answer (score 0):

well you have almost did it...

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
timer(.1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this kills my actual sleep, if i am setting up for 1 minute it takes more than minutes..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
import time
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw

def timer(hours):
    seconds = hours * 60
    start = time.time()

    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < seconds:

        time.sleep(0.0010)
        elapsed = time.time() - start

    elapsed = elapsed//60

    #tkMessageBox.showinfo("Done", "Done Today" +str(elapsed) + " Hrs")
    root.title("Done")
    label = tk.Label(root, text= "Done Today " +str(elapsed) + " Hrs" )
    label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=lambda: root.destroy())
    button.pack(side="bottom", fill="none", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

timer(1)
```

Comment: Earlier i had used this, found in different post here. But it looks odd with minimize,expand and close icons on corner of dialog.